# Flutter widget choice

Tags: flutter, widget

Im creating for my girlfriend app for her work that will store her customers with some details and dates when they comes to her.

It is my first application, and also im new to flutter, as far i have one screen where i have button when i pressed it, shows bottomsheet with form to add customer and additional info in to listviews Card that build in body on this screen.
Soo far i have that correct.
My problem is i want to add something like this...
when i click on that added card i want it to take to another screen or unwind/ show textfield for that specific card when she could add dates for that client.

Any suggestions for me what to change or what widget/method to use?

Answer (score 1):

You should implement a navigation so you can bring the user to a new page and pass an argument when you want to load the data. Best example is with the todo list : https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data

Comment: But if IT would be 40 customers it would mean i need to create 40 screens for them? I will check what you recommend me after work Thank you for your time

Comment: No, you would create only one screen(widget) that takes a Customer as a parameter. Then, you would pass in the customer you would like to show. Doesn't matter if they're 40 or 100.